# How can I add a subdomain to Admin Panel Laravel Backpack(backpackforlaravel)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-backpack, laravel-6.2

How can I add a subdomain to Admin Panel Laravel Backpack?
I want to add a subdomain to my Laravel Backpack admin panel, I need point 'admin.example.com' subdomain to Laravel Backpack admin Panel.
Laravel Backpack provides route prefix for Admin Panel.

I want to use the same project source code for the site, admin and API.

admin.example.com -> Admin

api.example.com -> API

www.example.com -> Site

Answer (score 3):

You can get Laravel Backpack to run under a subdomain, for example **admin.app.local**, instead of the prefix (for example app.local/admin) as follows:

In the **.env file**, you can define the admin subdomain, something useful if you work in different environments where it changes:

```
ADMIN_SUBDOMAIN = admin.app.local
```

Optionally you can also define in **config/app.php**, whether or not the admin will use subdomain, adding:

```
'use_admin_subdomain' => true,
```

Then in the **config/backpack/base.php** file, you will want to stop using the admin route prefix, since you will use admin in the subdomain, so you must define:

```
'route_prefix' => '',
```

Then in **routes/backpack/custom.php**, you will be able to include all routes under a new group, which will determine if the admin backpack runs under a subdomain (defined in app.use_admin_subdomain) and the subdomain (defined in env('ADMIN_SUBDOMAIN'), and all the original routes and groups will go within:

```
Route::group (
    config('app.use_admin_subdomain') ? ['domain' => env('ADMIN_SUBDOMAIN')]: []
    , function () {

  ... original backpack routes

});
```

Optionally in the same backpack routes file, you can remove the prefix of the original routes, commenting:

```
'prefix' => config ('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin'),
```

Although being empty in config/backpack/base.php has no effect yet without commenting.

You can follow the same procedure to define your API routes under the api.app.local subdomain, in that case in **routes/api.php** file.